# how to get equivalent of a number with restrict

Tags: php

Hello guys I want to add some restrict inside my condition in a function for a number,
 and I want to accept a number with just these criteria :

-"58xxx" with '58' in the first
-also accept it with space **" 58xxx"** or without space **"58xxx"**

how can i do that on php

i have done this before is it correct ?

```
'\[1]{1}[2]{5}[1-9]{3}'
```

Comment: is  it like this \s*58(\d){3} or like this \s*58(d){3} ? because phpstorm told me 'unclosed group'

Comment: still tel me the same  error ; if (preg_match('\s*58(\d{3})', $numbertotest))

Comment: thank you bro it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a simple regex.
This will test for

- any number of spaces
- '58'
- 3 digits

```php
$tests = [
  ' 58123',
  '     58123',
  '58123',
  '158123',
  '15813',
  ' 15813',
];

foreach($tests as $test) {
    echo $test, ': ', preg_match('/\s*58(\d{3})/', $test) ? 'true' : 'false', PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
58123: true
     58123: true
58123: true
158123: true
15813: false
 15813: false
```